# Spring service returns 200 but getting 404 in postman

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, jwt, postman

I am new into Spring REST, what I am trying to do is creating REST endpoints for a project. Also I am implementing JWT Spring Security into the service as per project requirement.
The first REST endpoint is /LOGIN, after user credentials are verified through this service a token is assigned to the client in the header. This token will hold the session for any further REST call authentication. This service is doing its work as expected.

The next REST service to be called is GET_CURRENT_USER, which does the work of validating the token and then further jobs. I am using the token in postman to call the GET_CURRENT_USER service, the service code works just fine and I am returning code 200 and the expected JSON through my service.

But at postman I am getting a 404 not found error. What I have tried:

1. Removed CORS filters
2. Added index.jsp to project, I get the index page in postman and not the 404 (but that doesn't help).
3. Tracing further calls after GET_CURRENT_USER, but that leads so many further calls and can't trace what exactly overrides my response with 404.
4. Tried to play with GET and POST methods in code and POSTMAN but no luck. I am using all the headers required and other stuff.

Can't figure out where could the problem located. I cannot share code, but can answer all questions related.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: 404, means you are trying to access the URL which is not available, can you check that

Comment: you should check your url, 404 = not found

Comment: Maybe you are forgiving some context path preceding the /LOGIN endpoint, such as "http://localhost:8080/deploymentcontext/LOGIN"?

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error went away when I provided default index.jsp, which was missing in my project. But it didn't solved my problem as I needed Rest response(JSON) in result. What I learnt from long code-debugging of DispatcheServlet and Filter chains etc.. that in case we need JSON response after rest call, and we don't intend to send any view-response(like jsps), we should implement AuthenticationSuccessHandler and return void.

Initially my spring-secuyrity.xml was as follows:

```
      <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <http pattern="/abc/login" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/abc/**" entry-point-ref="jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
<csrf disabled="true"/>
<custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthorizationTokenFilter"/>
    </http>
  <beans:bean id="jwtAuthorizationTokenFilter" class="com.abc.xyz.controller.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter">
<beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="<MyUserDetailsService>">
<password-encoder ref="encoder" />
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>  
<beans:bean id="encoder"/>
<class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
<beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

I changed it to as follows:

```
          <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <http pattern="/abc/login" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/abc/**" entry-point-ref="jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthorizationTokenFilter"/>
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="jwtAuthorizationTokenFilter" class="com.abc.xyz.controller.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authSuccessHandler" />
    </beans:bean>
   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="<MyUserDetailsService>">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>  

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Auth Success handler -->
    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.abc.xyz.controller.JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />   

    </beans:beans>
```

JWT:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
       // Not to do anything
    }
}
```

In the above code where we are setting 2 bean properties, that need not required to be in the JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter

The JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter extends to  AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter 
and I believe with reflection it sets authenticationManager, successHandler of the  AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

These are the following 2 methods I see in the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

```
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
      this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
     }
     public void setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
       AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
      Assert.notNull(successHandler, "successHandler cannot be null");
      this.successHandler = successHandler;
     }
```